# Is it possible to use interface parameters in PHP functions / methods

Tags: php, interface

I was wondering if it is possible to use interface parameters in PHP functions / methods.

I'm used to coding in .Net and using .Net this is possible, such as having the following interface:

```
interface IVehicleDataProvider
{
    public void Create(IVehicle Vehicle);
}
```

Then I could implement this in a class as such:

```
class CarDataProvider : IVehicleDataProvider
{
    public void Create(Car Car)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

or

```
class TruckDataProvider : IVehicleDataProvider
{
    public void Create(Truck Truck)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

as long as Car or Truck implements an IVehicle interface.

Can the same thing be done in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't define one type in the interface, and a different one (even though it's a subclass) in the implementor, the implementor must follow the interface completely.

But even if you define

```
function create(IVehicle $vehicle);
```

You can still pass in `Car`s and `Truck`s.

Comment: So I would define `function create(IVehicle $vehicle);` in the class and then when calling this function I could pass in a different type such as `VehicleDataProvider->Create(Car $car);`?

Comment: Exactly. This will only work, of course, assuming Car is extending IVehicle.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work becouse the declaration in the class must be fully compatible with the interface declaration so you have to use IVehicle as parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use interfaces in PHP 5, although they are still relatively immature. For the example above, you would use something like the following:

```
interface IVehicleDataProvider
{
    public function create(IVehicle $vehicle);
}

class CarDataProvider implements IVehicleDataProvider
{
    public function create(IVehicle $car) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

PHP does not support return type declaration, so you cannot declare a function void (although you should make note of the return type in the function documentation).

You also cannot extend an interface, so if you declare that the `create` function in the `IVehicleDataProvider` interface accepts an instance of `IVehicle`, then the `CarDataProvider::create`, function must accept an instance of the IVehicle interface.